# Скрытие LABEL при выборе элемента списка

Tags: javascript, html, css

друзья! Ниже представляю код, который полностью устраивает меня по функционалу, но в нем есть один недочет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы поле с заголовком (label) скрывалось и отображалось вместе с самим select. Выполните код и поймете о чем я говорю. Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

```js
$('#select1').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  //если элемент с id равным значению #select1 существует
  if($('#' + val).length){
     //скрываем все селекты шага 2
    $('#step2 select').hide();
    //показываем нужный
    $('#' + val).show();
    //в противном случае, если значение равняется "all"
  }else if(val == 'all'){
    //показать все списки шага2
    $('#step2 select').show();
  }
})
```

```css
#step2 select{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите</option>
<option value="select2_1">Список1</option>
<option value="select2_2">Список2</option>
<option value="all">Оба списка</option>
</select>

<div id="step2">
  <label><strong>Список №1:</strong></label>
  <select id="select2_1">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите(список1)</option>
<option>А</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>

<label><strong>Список №2:</strong></label>
  <select id="select2_2">
<option selected disabled>Выбирите(список2)</option>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {
  //скрываем все селекты шага 2
  $('#step2 select').hide().prev("label").hide();

  var val = $(this).val();
  //если элемент с id равным значению #select1 существует
  if ($('#' + val).length) {
    //показываем нужный
    $('#' + val).show().prev("label").show();
    //в противном случае, если значение равняется "all"
  } else if (val == 'all') {
    //показать все списки шага2
    $('#step2 select').show().prev("label").show();
  }
});
$('#select1').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option selected disabled>Выбeрите</option>
  <option value="select2_1">Список1</option>
  <option value="select2_2">Список2</option>
  <option value="all">Оба списка</option>
</select>

<div id="step2">
  <label><strong>Список №1:</strong></label>
  <select id="select2_1">
    <option selected disabled>Выбeрите(список1)</option>
    <option>А</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>

  <label><strong>Список №2:</strong></label>
  <select id="select2_2">
    <option selected disabled>Выбeрите(список2)</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
  </select>
</div>
```